# Pause the slider when a video appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a slider that was created for me years ago. The slider supports both images and video with a timer but the timer is for both, so for example if I set the timer to run every 10 seconds it would rotate the slider every 10 seconds. The issue I am facing is if the video isn't finished it would just cut off the video at 10 seconds.

**Here is the json file structure:**

```
// Json Object
var data = [{

    tags: [{
    name: 'a',
    content: '<img src="images/1.jpg">',
                cssanimate: 'fadeIn',
                attr: {
                    href: '#',
                    title: 'Image With Hyperlink'
                }
            }]
    },{
    tags: [{
        name: 'video',
        source: {
            mp4: 'sample2.mp4',
            ogg: ''
        }
    }]

}];

// Call Slider function
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#slideshow-slider').jSonSlider({
    'loadallslides': false,
    'auto': [true, '1000'],
    'nextprev': false,
    'circular': true,
    'pagi': false,
    'data': data
    });
});
```

What I need it to do is pause the slider when video is playing. After the video ended triggers, resume the slider. I believe the slider can be paused using the following (coming from the developer)

_this.find(’.playpause.pause’).trigger(‘click’)

**Here is the full js code:**
https://jsfiddle.net/wxvynp09/

Thank you! 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to create a **variable** that holds the video state and  a **function** that sets the video state. Inside the `<video>` tag, you can have `onplay` and `onpause` set the video state.

According to the jsFiddle you included in the question:

- On lines 308 - 336, if `obj_data[i].tags[tag].name == 'video'` it includes the `<video>` and `<source>` tag.

  - **On line 309, you can include the** `onplay` and `onpause` events.
  - set it to `tag_html += '<' + obj_data[i].tags[tag].name + 'onplay="setVideoState(true)" onpause="setVideoState(pause)" width="';`
- On lines 210 to 216, `autoSlide` is being assigned to an interval that automatically slides the slider.

  - **Modify the** `setInterval`, so it can only call `auto_slide_fun` if the video is **NOT** playing.

[**LINK TO JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/4b7gxm2c/)

Sources:

- [MDN Web Docs: onplay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onplay)
- [MDN Web Docs: onpause](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onpause)

### Example of onplay and onpause use

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video width="320" height="240" id="video" controls autoplay onplay="setVideoState(true)" onpause="setVideoState(false)">
  <source src="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
  var videoPlaying = false;
  function setVideoState(state){
       videoPlaying = state;
       console.log('videoPlaying: ',videoPlaying);
  }
  
  function auto_slide(){
    console.log("auto_slide function called!");
  }
  
  setInterval(function(){
    // only call auto_slide function if the video is NOT playing
    if(!videoPlaying){
      auto_slide();
    }
  }, 2500);
  
  
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this reply - very detailed! I'm looking into what you said but a little confused on how to modify the setInterval part...

Comment: @code_secret I updated the code snippet above. I added an `auto_slide` function and `setInterval`.

Comment: Great thanks but I have no idea where this goes ;) Does that <script> tag replace line 210 to 216?

Comment: In jsfiddle there is separate boxes for HTML, CSS, and JS . The `<script>` tag just allow me to add JavaScript code in a HTML file... it is not needed. It is just an example to show you `onplay` and `onpause` in use. please look at the jsFiddle link in my answer as it includes my modifications. You will see the changes I made in the lines listed in my answer.